# beveling two different ways

Tags: bevel

I was experimenting with engraving. I started with the grey box.  I beveled the corners and edges.  Then I engraved text into one of the faces of the box.  The super-sharp edges left around the text would not do so I beveled them.  This operation affected the original beveling. Didn't want that.

What's the answer? Is there a way to select an area that isn't a complete object and perform the bevel operation on that only?  Engrave and bevel a new object then integrate it with the original?